# Set Integer header value in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, web-services, header, http-headers, httpclient

I want to set an Int Header value for terminalId.

Currently HttpClient header only takes <String, String> pairs. How can I add a header with <String, int>?

This Web service accept Int for terminalId.

Following Code :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8678");
                var postview = new CitizenResult
                {
                    cpartyUsername = "abc",
                    cpartyPassword = "123",
                };
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", "d448f575db31a44e32e0a17f24bc947cdd4edb4a7db8729734c81b9e139286af36dd9c5e42793d494e0f7bd45b25e5f3b77472949f38bcdb3dfa2b8d1ef376848ec6ce65b9a7d7be343c5c1b59089082");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("clientIPAddress", "178.173.147.4");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("clientAgentInfo", "192.168.0.227");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("terminalId", 123);
                int a = 190766;
                var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<CitizenResult>("http://test", postview);
                postTask.Wait();
                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var x = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<SalamtResultViewModel>();
                    ViewBag.x = x;

                }
                else
                {
                    var x = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<badRequestResult>();
                    ViewBag.x = x;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Convert the int to string before putting it into header, and then convert it back to int after reading it from the header.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the integer just call the .toString() method.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("terminalId", 123.toString());
```

or

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("terminalId", a.toString());
```

This is because the header can be considered as just a JSON object where everything is stored in quotes like this:

```
{
   "key":  "value"
}
```

so your entry would be stored like this

```
"terminalId": "123"
```

JSON can hold information like:

```
"terminalId": 123
```

but there are no overloads available for that.

Comment: Thanks for your attention but the web service accept Int for terminalId.

Comment: Sorry but you are not passing in to the web service.  You are passing in to a System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders object's property which MUST have a string.   I think you need to look up about that namespace and what casting is.  I think you've copied this code from somewhere?  You are constructing a JSON request, and it doesn't take integers.  What you are trying to do is impossible.  TL;DR pass in "123" not 123